# Angular project creation failed due to "npm ERR! path Angular\appTwo\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Following are the steps that I used to create my very first angular application.

- Install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- Install VSCode
- Checked my NodeJS and npm versions

[image]

- executed `npm install -g @angular/cli` and I received the following log in my VSCode's integrated terminal (which is fine, I believe)

```html
> PS C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular> npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> 
C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
+ @angular/cli@6.1.3
updated 1 package in 75.927s
PS C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular>
```

- executed `ng new appTwo` to create my app. Below are the logs and error I received.

```html
PS C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular> ng new appTwo
CREATE appTwo/angular.json (3548 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/package.json (1312 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/README.md (1023 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/index.html (293 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/tsconfig.app.json (170 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/environments/environment.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (995 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/app/app.component.ts (210 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (302 bytes)
CREATE appTwo/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular\appTwo\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular\appTwo\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-12T05_56_04_185Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
PS C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular>
```

Here what I did after googling about Angular's project creation issues

1. Uninstalled NodeJS and Angular and reinstalled both, but the same problem occurred.
2. Restarted my VSCode but it was no good.
3. Installed acorn through `npm install -g acorn` because of the error is received. But the same error occurred again.

[image]

4. Installed Angular cli using `npm install @angular/cli` in my local folder "Angular" and then executed new project command `ng new appTwo`. No progress was received.

I understand that "npm" is unable to find 'acorn' from the path "C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn". There is no 'acorn' folder inside "node_modules". But I do not know how to resolve this problem.

Here is the complete log of the command run

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'acorn' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose npm-session 0648b6c8ae8267c4
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn 896ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for acorn@latest fetched in 954ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
13 silly resolveWithNewModule acorn@5.7.1 checking installable status
14 silly currentTree npm
15 silly idealTree npm
15 silly idealTree `-- acorn@5.7.1
16 silly install generateActionsToTake
17 silly diffTrees action count 1
18 silly diffTrees add acorn@5.7.1
19 silly decomposeActions action count 8
20 silly decomposeActions fetch acorn@5.7.1
21 silly decomposeActions extract acorn@5.7.1
22 silly decomposeActions preinstall acorn@5.7.1
23 silly decomposeActions build acorn@5.7.1
24 silly decomposeActions install acorn@5.7.1
25 silly decomposeActions postinstall acorn@5.7.1
26 silly decomposeActions finalize acorn@5.7.1
27 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json acorn@5.7.1
28 silly install executeActions
29 silly doSerial global-install 8
30 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
31 verbose lock using C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-51cfd9b4628f34cb.lock for C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
32 silly doParallel extract 8
33 silly extract acorn@5.7.1
34 silly pacote trying acorn@https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.1.tgz by hash: sha512-d+nbxBUGKg7Arpsvbnlq61mc12ek3EY8EQldM3GPAhWJ1UVxC6TDGbIvUMNU6obBX3i1+ptCIzV4vq0gFPEGVQ==
35 silly pacote acorn@https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.1.tgz extracted to C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\acorn-4f034420 by content address 24ms
36 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 8
37 silly doSerial remove 8
38 silly doSerial move 8
39 silly doSerial finalize 8
40 silly finalize C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn
41 silly doParallel refresh-package-json 8
42 silly refresh-package-json C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn
43 silly doParallel preinstall 8
44 silly preinstall acorn@5.7.1
45 info lifecycle acorn@5.7.1~preinstall: acorn@5.7.1
46 silly doSerial build 8
47 silly build acorn@5.7.1
48 info linkStuff acorn@5.7.1
49 silly linkStuff acorn@5.7.1 has C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules as its parent node_modules
50 silly linkStuff acorn@5.7.1 is part of a global install
51 silly linkStuff acorn@5.7.1 is installed into a global node_modules
52 silly linkStuff acorn@5.7.1 is installed into the top-level global node_modules
53 verbose linkBins acorn@5.7.1
54 verbose linkBins [ { acorn: './bin/acorn' },
54 verbose linkBins   'C:\\Users\\Babar Baig\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm',
54 verbose linkBins   true ]
55 verbose linkMans acorn@5.7.1
56 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-51cfd9b4628f34cb.lock for C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
57 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn'
58 verbose cwd C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular
59 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
60 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "acorn"
61 verbose node v8.11.3
62 verbose npm  v5.6.0
63 error path C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn
64 error code ENOENT
65 error errno -4058
66 error syscall chmod
67 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\Babar Baig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn'
68 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
69 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I found it from "\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs". Any help would be much appreciated as it's my very first experience with Angular.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this and then comment the result `ng new test-project --skip-install` then `cd test-project` and `npm install`.

Comment: Same error occurred. Here is the result.
...
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular\test-project\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\Babar Baig\Desktop\Angular\test-project\node_modules\acorn\bin\acorn'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: It must be your **npm** problem update your **npm**. the latest update is 6.3.0

Comment: I installed the latest version (6.3.0) of npm but I am facing the same error again. :(

Comment: Did you try this throw the proxy?

Comment: No proxy. I simply put "npm install npm@latest -g" on terminal and upgraded npm.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to manually place the culprit 'acorn' into node-modules bin?

Comment: I'll search for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following link to solve the issue
[docs.npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache).
I executed `npm cache clean --force` to clean my npm cache. I created a new Angular project after cleaning npm cache and it worked perfectly fine.

Happy Coding!