# As i run my Angular project with " ng serve --open " I get an error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

How should I resolve this issue? I tried these two commands :

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But I'm getting the same error - I also checked the `ClassPath`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular project creation failed due to "npm ERR! path Angular\appTwo\node\_modules\acorn\bin\acorn"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806324/angular-project-creation-failed-due-to-npm-err-path-angular-apptwo-node-module)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
2. npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
3. npm install

Comment: D:\Mindshare Baseline Web Portal\To_Do_List\todolistApp>ng serve --open
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^9.0.0-beta || >=9.0.0 <10.0.0,
but Angular version 8.2.14 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: And Please can u tell me how those 3 commands removed the previous error . Can u pls explain what was wrong?

Comment: https://thecodebuzz.com/this-version-of-cli-is-only-compatible-with-angular-version-or-but-found-instead/
hope this helps you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli,
npm cache clear --force,
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest or npm install @angular/cli

Comment: yes i tried it but getting another error now to update firebaseapp

Comment: can you please attach snap shot of firebase error what you getting

Answer (score 0):

I got this reference while searching :

[Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662571/uncaught-referenceerror-importdefault-is-not-defined)

This fixed it for me.

Added these lines to polyfills.ts:

const w: any = window
// Fix "missing __importDefault", as per https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32215#issuecomment-543459862
w.__importDefault = (w && w.__importDefault) || function (mod) { return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod }; }

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to fix the angular cli compatibility issue run the below :

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

and to check the version run :

```
ng --version
```

to fix the 'acorn'module missing try with this:

```
npm install acorn --save
```

or

```
npm install acorn --unsafe-perm --save
```